# ASP.NET how to populate html table on asp button click

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am trying to populate an html table with rows based on what a c# function returns on a button click.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Populate" /></div><br>

<table id ="randtable" class="tablex">
  <tr>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th>Col2</th>
    <th>Col3</th>
    <th>Col4</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and my Button1_Click function looks like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Entity> x = someFunction();
    //I want to have each row in the table represent each entity. Assume each entity has 4 attributes which would go in Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 in the table.
}
```

Any idea how to do this? The reason I'm sticking with an html table instead of an asp control table is to keep the css of the html table, unless there's a way to make the asp table look appealing as well.

Comment: Try one of the many ASP.net data controls: GridView, ListView, Repeater. They are designed with this in mind. Repeater is the "lightest" option. Gridview proabalbly the heaviest.

Comment: There is a property for ASP.net controls called "CssClass" which is the same as the "class" of HTML controls..

Answer (score 2):

Put your table inside a ListView Control:

```
<asp:ListView runat=server id="lvResults">
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <table id ="randtable" class="tablex">
     <tr>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
      <th>Col3</th>
      <th>Col4</th>
    </tr>
   <asp:PlaceHolder id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
  </table>
 </LayoutTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
   <td><%# Eval(Container.DataItem, "col1") %></td>
   <td><%# Eval(Container.DataItem, "col2") %></td>
   <td><%# Eval(Container.DataItem, "col3") %></td>
  </tr>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Then put the following in your code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Entity> x = someFunction();
    lvResults.DataSource = x;
    lvResults.DataBind()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want to do it on html table then you can use runat="server" on your table's tbody element then populate your table's rows inside a loop.

your table like this:

> ```
>  <table id ="randtable" class="tablex">   
>   <thead>   
>    <tr>
>      <th>Col1</th>
>      <th>Col2</th>   
>    </tr> 
>   </thead> 
>   <tbody id="mybody" runat="server">
>      //your dynamic rows from code behind
>   </tbody> 
>  </table>
> ```

and your class should have something like this:

> ```
> protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
>    List<Entity> x = someFunction();
>    foreach (var entity in x)
>        {
>            mybody.InnerHtml += string.Format("<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td></tr>", 
>                                              entity.value1, entity.value2);
>        }
> }
> ```